# Avoid starting MySQL on startup on Raspbian

Tags: boot, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a MySQL server running under Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi. How can I prevent the MySQL server starting on system startup?

I read everywhere that I have to make changes in the `/etc/init/mysql.conf` file or do `echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override`, but in my `/etc/init/` there is no file at all with mysql in its name.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue on my server too. I dont want pure-ftpd to start.

This may not be the answer you like, but there is a sort of "ghetto" work around:

Before exit 0 in the /etc/rc.local script add this line:

```
sudo pkill <process name>
```

you can just find the process name by using top and have the sql server running.

if you dont like the pkill, you can put this inside your rc.local

```
sudo service stop <service name>
```

You can get an idea of the service name of your service name by running in terminal:

```
find /etc/rc* | grep "sql"
```

Rc.local gets executed after all the startup scripts so the sql will be up for less than a second but will immediately terminate.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/automatic-start.html) you may find an [init.d](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=update-rc.d) script responsible for starting the service at boot.

If that's the case, consider the following:

### Determine if you have an init.d script:

```
sudo ls -al /etc/init.d/*sql*
```

Take note of the name, according to the docs it should be **mysql.server**, it may also be symlinked as **mysql**.

### Disable via `update-rc.d` command:

If the name of the script is in fact **mysql.server**, then this command should disable the service:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql.server disable
sudo update-rc.d mysql.server stop
```

In theory you can still start/stop it on demand:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mysql.server
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
```

If you wanted to permanently remove it:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/mysql.server
sudo update-rc.d mysql.server remove
sudo killall --regex .*mysql.*
sudo reboot
```

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`# apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`

then

`# sysv-rc-conf`

Then just look for `mysql` and uncheck all runlevels.  You can also disable other run time scripts, but be careful with ones you don't know about as many are needed for a properly functioning system.